# Navicat Query plan

Tags: sql, navicat

How can I see the execution plan of a mysql query in navicat ?

[Navicat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVWyb.png)

Comment: google is your friend? "navicat show query plan". More details would assist us. Did the query run and produce results before you tried to look at the plan?

Comment: I made a deep search on google before I asked.  Of course...

Comment: As did I. What happens when you select the  'explain plan' button? What version of navicat are you using? Please provide details of your environment?  Does the 'explain plan' work with a simple query? Is it available in the version of 'navcat' that you have? There are other ways of getting formatted 'explain plan' for queries with free software.

Comment: The 'explain plan' button just give details about possible keys, number of rows, filtered rows etc but doesnt give any information on the algorithm the system uses to execute the query. I am using navicat 11.2.6.

Comment: Time to show us what you are seeing? Screen shot or report?  I use 'Navicat Lite' version 10.0.3. It seems to provide useful information.

Comment: I posted a link to the screenshot.

Comment: This is the screenshot with the explain plan.

Comment: My bad - sorry - what is your complaint about the explain plan output?